# Positioning tip labels next to the tips in the dendrogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendrogram, phylogeny, dendextend

I read in a tree (`.nex`), convert it to `dendro` class, and plot it using `ggdendrogram` from `ggplot2`. How can I position the tip labels next to the tips in the dendrogram and not at the bottom?

```
mytree <- read.nexus('mytree.nex')
den_data_mytree <- dendro_data(as.dendrogram(mytree))
pdf('mytree.pdf', h=55,w=55)
ggdendrogram(den_data_mytree, theme_dendro=F, labels=F) +
  labs(x = "x label", y = "y label", title = "Title") + 
  geom_text(data = den_data_mytree$labels, aes(x, y, label = label,color=den_data_mytree$labels$group), hjust = 1.2, size = 9, angle=90) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("purple","orange")) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=24), axis.title=element_text(size=54,face="bold"), title = element_text(size=54), legend.title = element_blank())
dev.off()
```

The output is this image:

[image: ggdendogram]

Here is the data:

```
>dput(core_snp_tree)
structure(list(edge = structure(c(109L, ..., 108L), .Dim = c(213L, 2L)), edge.length = c(0.00373, 0,  3e-05, ..., 0.00844), Nnode = 106L,      node.label = c("", "100.00", ..., "100.00"), tip.label = c("list","of","tip","labels"), root.edge = 0), class = "phylo", order = "cladewise")
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(mytree)`?

Comment: It is in the following format:
```> dput(core_snp_tree)

structure(list(edge = structure(c(109L, ..., 108L), .Dim = c(213L, 2L)), edge.length = c(0.00373, 0, 
3e-05, ..., 0.00844), Nnode = 106L, 
    node.label = c("", "100.00", ..., "100.00"), tip.label = c("list","of","tip","labels"), root.edge = 0), class = "phylo", order = "cladewise")
```

Comment: The dput seems wrong:
```
> core_snp_tree <- structure(list(edge = structure(c(109L, ..., 108L), .Dim = c(213L, 2L)), edge.length = c(0.00373, 0,  3e-05, ..., 0.00844), Nnode = 106L,      node.label = c("", "100.00", ..., "100.00"), tip.label = c("list","of","tip","labels"), root.edge = 0), class = "phylo", order = "cladewise")
Error in structure(c(109L, ..., 108L), .Dim = c(213L, 2L)) : 
  '...' used in an incorrect context
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use the [dendextend](https://talgalili.github.io/dendextend/) package, with the `hang.dendrogram` function together with ggdend (the simplest way is to use ggplot call on the dendrogram object). In general, dendextend::ggdend is a more extended version of ggdendro.

Example:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests[1:5, ]), "ave")
library(dendextend)
dend <- hang.dendrogram(as.dendrogram(hc))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dend)
```

[image]

For more details, see [here](https://talgalili.github.io/dendextend/articles/dendextend.html#ggplot2-integration-1).

Comment: When I try the command

dend <- hang.dendrogram(as.dendrogram(hc))

with my nexus tree (from Raxml), I get this error: 
'Error in ape::as.hclust.phylo(object) : the tree is not ultrametric'

What should I do next?

Comment: It means you probably have some branches that are smaller then their leaves. You should take a look at your tree and see if it "makes sense"

Comment: You may also have a bunch of leaves with height of 0...